# Is It necessary to release the memory of View using IBOutlets?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview

i  am new to iphone application development, here i have one doubt in solving memory issues of my app, i drag and drop UIWebview using IB, after that i created IBOutlet to this webview .. it is necessary to release the memory of this  webiview after use...can any one help me...

### in .h

```
IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
```

### in .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


webview.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self request]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webview loadRequest:request];
webview.opaque=YES;
webview.scalesPageToFit=YES;

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

if it is necessary to release the memory used webview , in which place i can release it ...
Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html),

> Objects in the nib file are created with a retain count of 1 and then autoreleased. As it rebuilds the object hierarchy, UIKit reestablishes connections between the objects using setValue:forKey:, which uses the available setter method or retains the object by default if no setter method is available.

Not that the available setter method is generally a retained one. So if you are not using ARC then you need to release IBOutlets. one suitable place to release is the `dealloc` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not enable ARC, then the answer is YES, its necessary to release IBOutlets

**in which place i can release it?**

You can release this objects in dealloc method and also its a good practice to set `nil` to these objects in `viewDidUnload`

```
-(void)dealloc
{
   [self.webview release];
   [super dealloc];
}

-(void)viewDidUnload
{
   [super viewDidUnload];
   self.webview = nil;
}
```

Comment: here i didn't declare property for UIWebView , in this case also it is necessary to release memory?

Comment: @Krrish, if setter is not available then UIKit retains them. So you have to worry. I have already said in the comment of other answer that the best policy is to specify the property to avoid the confusion.

Comment: @taskinoor, Normally i will specify the property for an IBOutlet. Thanks for the info... upvote for that

Comment: @JilaniBasha, refering to taskinoor's comment, then also you have to worry about releasing the object..

Answer (score 0):

If you have `@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet  UIWebView *webview;` and synthesis it in `.m file` then you have to explicitly release the memory of your web view

You should refer [Memory Management Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1)

Comment: i didn't declare properties to UIWebView Then what i have to do...it is necessary to release the memory used by UIWebView...

Comment: If the property is not declared, i.e. the setter is not available then by default that is retained. So you should worry about releasing it. Please check the resource programming guide for details. I think it's best to specify setter/property to avoid the confusion.

Comment: @taskinoor: aren't NIB components auto release ?

Comment: from above answer,@krrish is also told that not necessary to release the memory of NIB components..can if fallow it ...?

Comment: @Maulik, no. They are first autoreleased but later UIKit retain then again if no setter is available. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Maulik, removing the downvote as you have updated your answer.

Comment: @taskinoor: I am not telling that u r wrong but I think its good practice to only release object that you have own with new,alloc,init, copy ... No ???

Comment: @Maulik, I think this is one exceptional case. This is not about good practice, you will get memory leak if you don't release. It's been a long time that I have not worked with iOS, so I might be wrong ... but this is what I remember about memory management of nib files.